# getting error when running app as iPad instead of iPhone in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, uibutton

I have a project I have been working on.  It was a iPhone only project, but have recently found out that I need to make it available to iPad as well.  In theory, I should be able to put in some if statement to switch between iPhone/iPad code, but I'm running into a small problem.  On my initial view, I am getting the infamous error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x8a2dcf0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key loginButton.'
```

loginButton is pointing to a UIButton, and everything in my Login_iPad.xib is linked correctly.

I'm sure I'm missing something small, but any help would be VERY appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is some of my code in AppDelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOption:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    UIViewController *rootView = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];
} else {
    UIViewController *rootView = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login_iPad" bundle:nil];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];
}
```

**UPDATE:**  If I remove all of the outlets (including the view outlet), I, of course, get this error:

```
loaded the "Login_iPad" nib but the view outlet was not set
```

But, if I add even just the outlet for the view, I get this:

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view
```

Doesn't make sense to me.  I have the class of the XIB set to the same class as the iPhone XIB.  But, I know I'm overlooking something.

I can't seem to link ANYTHING when running as an iPad app.  Not even the view ... or it throws out that error.

Comment: Sounds like an outlet in your iPad nib is not linked correctly...

Comment: There is some problem in your xib, have you checked all the properties if there is any warning present there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok ... not sure why this fixed my issue.  But, I removed the value for "Main Interface" for both iphone and ipad within the project summary.  And it ran just fine.  Very odd.

I don't know if this made a difference, but I also changed this in my appdelegate:

```
UIViewController *rootView;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    rootView = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login_iPad" bundle:nil];
} else {
    rootView = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
}
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];
```

Comment: Spent way too much time trying to figure this out. Thank you

Comment: It was changing the Main Interface to Main Window that worked for me.

Comment: I could kiss you. I had the exact same problem(s) OVER AND OVER and spent hours pouring through my code only to erase the "Main Interface" in project and it works fine. I have similar code in App Delegate, and for the record, didn't change it and it still solved the problem. What the hell...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've check the target/Summary/Devices and its set to universal.

[image]

Comment: I've done that.  Thank you though.  I've deleted and re-added all of my connections in the xib file.  And it's attached to the correct class.  Very frustrating ... and I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking.

Comment: Make sure the spelling is exactly the same in both xib's sometimes a tiny typo, (such as a - instead of _) can cause untold grief.We know the problem is with the "loginButton" so check everything concerning that. Also broken connections can cause this error. Connections made and then deleted in code but still connected in the xib.

Comment: I can use the same .h and .m files for both xib files ... correct?

Comment: Heres an example of how to do it: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44472/1763/page/2